# Django cookies not persistent on page reload

Tags: python, django, cookies

In my simple e commerce store project I noticed that when I enter a value in the quantity field for the first time after entering the dev site everything works fine, but if I try to reload the page and reenter the quantity I get an error to enable my cookies why is that? My cookies are enabled and the `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7`

Comment: Have you checked your cookie domain?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN